# Calculated Fields from pivot table in SQL statement not calculating properly

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot-table

In my SQL code I created a a PIVOT table  to alter the columns.  I am trying to add 2 CALCULATED columns called PendingEffectiveness and ClosingRatio based on the pivot table columns I created but it's not calculating properly because all I'm getting is zeros.  Here is my SQL code:

```
-- Code for Summary Page
SELECT AdjusterName
    ,COALESCE(BeginningPending,0) as BeginningPending
    ,COALESCE(TransferredIn,0) as TransferredIn
    ,COALESCE(TransferredOut,0) as TransferredOut 
    ,COALESCE(FeaturesPending,0) as FeaturesPending 
    ,COALESCE(NewFeatures,0) as NewFeatures
    ,COALESCE(ClosedFeatures,0) as ClosedFeatures
    ,COALESCE(BeginningPending / FeaturesPending,0) * 100 as PendingEffectiveness
    ,COALESCE(ClosedFeatures / NewFeatures,0) / 100 as ClosingRatio
FROM 
(
    SELECT AdjusterName, [Type], COALESCE(FeatureCount,0) as FeatureCount
    FROM [dbo].[RPT_FeaturesByLitigationAdjuster]
    GROUP BY AdjusterName, Type, FeatureCount
) as SourceTable 
PIVOT (SUM([FeatureCount]) FOR [Type] in ([BeginningPending], [TransferredIn], [TransferredOut], [FeaturesPending], [NewFeatures], [ClosedFeatures])) as PivotTable;
```

Here is my query result set:

```
AdjusterName BeginningPending TransferredIn TransferredOut 
FeaturesPending NewFeatures ClosedFeatures PendingEffectiveness ClosingRatio

dstallings  51  2   0   53  0   57  0   0
jstrother   28  164 3   36  0   56  0   0
lfaulkner   247 23  8   259 22  94  0   0
rpatton     197 32  12  231 30  59  0   0
```

Comment: jarlh, are you just including the column names so that they fit in the window because you excluded columns?

Comment: I suspect you are doing  integer division.    Perhaps something like ,COALESCE(( BeginningPending * 100.0 ) / FeaturesPending,0)   ... Notice the * 100.0

Comment: Yes, John I am doing integer division.  That got it!  Thanks for the reply.